# How does my firm get a jar into a maven repo so maven projects can access it from inhouse

Tags: java, maven, nexus

How does my firm get a jar into a maven repo so maven projects can access it from inhouse.

Can someone please point me to a good step by step details on how to do the following

Make a jar with Maven
Get the jar installed into a local maven repo

Comment: What have you tried? And http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html already has some info.

Comment: You should be exploring publishing your company artifacts to "your" archiva and artifactory repos rather than thinking of publishing your company artifacts to public maven repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### I doubt your company wants their private internal code hosted on a public repository:

Install your own repository server inside your own network, I use [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi). This is the most ideal solution, then you can set up Mavenized projects to automatically upload themselves to your private repository when you do `mvn:release` and everyone will see the new versions. How to use Archiva is all [very well documented](http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.3.6/userguide/deploy.html).

#### If they have open source code that want to share, that is different:

You can [publish public facing open source code through Sonatype](http://www.vertigrated.com/blog/2011/03/releasing-maven-artifacts-to-central-repository-through-sonatype/).

#### If you just want to install a dependency to a local repository:

If you just want to install a `.jar` locally that is [easy and well documented](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html).

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                          -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                          -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                          -Dversion=version \
                          -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: you have this 100% right.. can you please post a sample of the pom.xml of the project that would make a jar and release it to the firms repo

Comment: Achiva, Artifactory, Nexus (what I use) - the choice is yours.  Get in to one of them and it will explain how to set up your pom's <distributionManagement> section correctly.

Comment: Be aware that releasing through Sonatype OSS is only for open source projects or for licenses that allow free distribution. See Sonatype [OSS Maven Repository Usage Guide](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Repository/Sonatype+OSS+Maven+Repository+Usage+Guide) under "1a. Terms of Service"

Comment: @techsjs2013 - You are better off asking the people who run your firm's repo about how to do that.  (You don't just put it in your POM.  You also put some magic stuff in your "$HOME/.m2/settings.xml" file.)

Comment: my firm dont have anyone else. this is going to be the first setup for the development team to share core objects